# Getting stdout from Process (NSTask) sometimes fails

Tags: process, foundation, nstask

I have a wrapper function around `Process` to easy call some external procedures (similar to pythonic `check_output`):

```
struct Output {
  public var code: Int32
  public var stdout: String
  public var stderr: String
}

func env(workingDir: String, command: [String]) -> Output {
  let stdout = Pipe()
  let stderr = Pipe()
  let process = Process()

  process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
  process.arguments = command
  process.standardError = stderr
  process.standardOutput = stdout
  process.currentDirectoryPath = workingDir

  var out = Data()
  var err = Data()

  stdout.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { fh in
    out.append(fh.availableData)
  }
  stderr.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { fh in
    err.append(fh.availableData)
  }

  process.launch()
  process.waitUntilExit()

  let code = process.terminationStatus
  let outstr = String(data: out, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
  let errstr = String(data: err, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""

  return .init(code: code, stdout: outstr, stderr: errstr)
}
```

Unfortunately, sometimes it fails. I'm building a small program, that runs thousands of those, for example:

```
env(workingDir: ".", command: ["file", "-b", "--mime-type", file.path])
```

And sometimes, very very rarely it outputs nothing with exit code 0.

I tried to reproduce it in tests:

```
func testEnv() {
  let checkEcho: (String) -> () -> () = { mode in {
    let speech = "Hello, \(mode) world!"
    let output = autoreleasepool {
      Process.env(workingDir: ".", command: ["echo", speech])
    }
    XCTAssertEqual(output.code, 0)
    XCTAssertEqual(output.stderr, "")
    XCTAssertEqual(output.stdout, speech + "\n")
  } }
  let performNTimesLoop: (Int, () -> Void) -> Void = {
    for _ in 0..<$0 { $1() }
  }
  let performNTimesConc: (Int, () -> Void) -> Void = { count, code in
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(
      iterations: count, execute: { _ in code() })
  }
  performNTimesLoop(1000, checkEcho("serial"))
  performNTimesConc(1000, checkEcho("concurrent"))
}
```

It goes very well for serial loop, but for concurrent one it is failing systematically. Although, I don't have concurrency in my program (but I want to add some in near future), I think the reasons of failing are might be similar. I tried to add some Locks, Semaphores and DispatchGroups here and there, but got no luck.

This is very annoying, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**UPD.** As I understand this happens because it is possible that final `outstr` creation will execute before last callback (`readabilityHandler`) will finish, as it runs on background thread. In confirmation of this today I got ThreadSanitizer triggered on

```
...
    out.append(fh.availableData) // modifying access
...
  let outstr = String(data: out, encoding: .utf8) ?? "" //read acces
...
```

But I can't figure out a way to say "wait until every readability callbalck will finish to execute". Is it even possible? May be I need some other api to do that? At first glance it seems like this is a trivial task to be solved with high level api.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is no way to achieve this with `FileHandle`, instead I've gone to lower api.

If somebody interested, there is actually very similar code in SwiftPM utility – https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Sources/Basic/Process.swift (see `Process.popen` or `Process.checkNonZeroExit`)